# Align two divs horizontally

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having trouble trying to align two divs in a wordpress page. Here is my code:

```css
    div.container {
    width: 100%;
    }

    div.left {
    float: left; 
    }

    div.right {
    float: right; 
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">

    <div class="left">
    <p id="cagliari" class="rtejustify" style="text-align: left;">Text Text Text</p>
    <iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12364.675124477504!2d9.1242403!3d39.2163323!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xad759bffc1fbf334!2sItalSecurity+Agency+%7C+Agenzia+Investigativa!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1469542451708" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>

    <div class="right">
    <p id="oristano" class="rtejustify" style="text-align: left;">Text Text Text</p>
    <iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3060.6645205664345!2d8.584972315150939!3d39.90414279457802!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x12dd9be3f40242ad%3A0x11a591da0ed6a074!2sItal%40Security+Agency!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1469543170307" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
    
    </div>
```

But it doesn't works properly

Comment: Are you sure that your CSS is loaded properly? I've tested your HTML & CSS and it worked fine. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/y98bff9e/

Comment: `width: 100%` means they span the whole row. make it 50% without margins or if they are take them in account

Answer (score 3):

Just use `float: left` and `width 1/2` on both div

```css
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    }

    .div {
    float: left; 
      width: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="div">
    <p id="cagliari" class="rtejustify" style="text-align: left;">Text Text Text</p>
    <iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12364.675124477504!2d9.1242403!3d39.2163323!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xad759bffc1fbf334!2sItalSecurity+Agency+%7C+Agenzia+Investigativa!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1469542451708" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>

    <div class="div">
    <p id="oristano" class="rtejustify" style="text-align: left;">Text Text Text</p>
    <iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3060.6645205664345!2d8.584972315150939!3d39.90414279457802!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x12dd9be3f40242ad%3A0x11a591da0ed6a074!2sItal%40Security+Agency!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1469543170307" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote

**Give 
**display:inline-block;**
for both div elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to assign `width` to both your `.left` and `.right` and even to `iframes` present insides those div.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.container {
width: 100%;
}

.container > .left {
float: left; 
width:49%;
height:auto;
}

.container > .right {
float:right; 
width:49%;
height:auto;
margin-left:1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="left">
<p id="cagliari" class="rtejustify" style="text-align: left;">Text Text Text</p>
<iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12364.675124477504!2d9.1242403!3d39.2163323!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xad759bffc1fbf334!2sItalSecurity+Agency+%7C+Agenzia+Investigativa!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1469542451708" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
<div class="right">
<p id="oristano" class="rtejustify" style="text-align: left;">Text Text Text</p>
<iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3060.6645205664345!2d8.584972315150939!3d39.90414279457802!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x12dd9be3f40242ad%3A0x11a591da0ed6a074!2sItal%40Security+Agency!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1469543170307" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Antonio102 accept the answer if above codes worked.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```css
    div.container {
        width: 100%;
        display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
   display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
        }
    div.right {
      margin-left:10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="left">
    <p id="cagliari" class="rtejustify" style="text-align: left;">Text Text Text</p>
    <iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12364.675124477504!2d9.1242403!3d39.2163323!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xad759bffc1fbf334!2sItalSecurity+Agency+%7C+Agenzia+Investigativa!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1469542451708" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>

    <div class="right">
    <p id="oristano" class="rtejustify" style="text-align: left;">Text Text Text</p>
    <iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3060.6645205664345!2d8.584972315150939!3d39.90414279457802!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x12dd9be3f40242ad%3A0x11a591da0ed6a074!2sItal%40Security+Agency!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1469543170307" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is using `flex-box`

`flex-box` also help you to achieve **responsiveness** also. I've added `media-query` of **just one line** to make it responsive on mobile screen. In mobile screen it will come like one below the other and in desktop it will come side by side (You can remove media-query if you dont want).

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container div{
  margin: 1em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  div.container{
   flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="left">
    <p id="cagliari" class="rtejustify" style="text-align: left;">Text Text Text</p>
    <iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d12364.675124477504!2d9.1242403!3d39.2163323!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xad759bffc1fbf334!2sItalSecurity+Agency+%7C+Agenzia+Investigativa!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1469542451708" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>

    <div class="right">
    <p id="oristano" class="rtejustify" style="text-align: left;">Text Text Text</p>
    <iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3060.6645205664345!2d8.584972315150939!3d39.90414279457802!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x12dd9be3f40242ad%3A0x11a591da0ed6a074!2sItal%40Security+Agency!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1469543170307" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
    
</div>
```

Here is the updated **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xgcedrr8/)**